# Converting shp file (sf object) to osm pbf?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, spatial, shapefile, r-sf

I have googled about this problem but I can't find a solution to this.

I've had shp shapefils loaded onto R using st_read. I want to write the shapefiles to OSM .pbf format.

Here's a sample code for your reference:

```
library(sf)
adminstrativeboundary2018 <- st_read("adminstrative_boun.shp")
st_write(adminstrativeboundary2018, dsn = "adminstrativeboundary2018.shp", layer = "adminstrativeboundary2018.pbf", driver = "OSM")
```

Any suggestions of how I can write my original shapefile to pbf (I need to convert my shapefile into osm's pbf format).

Comment: i assume it would be a good start to save it as a .pbf instead of .shp as you are doing in your code. not sure if that alone does it though

Comment: Data is available in ESRI shapefile and I want to use it for Open Trip Planner that accepts only .pbf street networks.

Comment: Hi @Xaviermoros. Please find my answer below. I hope it will solve your problem. If so, please consider marking this answer as "accepted" and/or "upvoted". If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers

Comment: Hi this was really helpful and I have accepted your solution. I have managed to convert my shp to osm but not .osm.pbf as you have said. That doesn't pop up in box. Instead, I've found .osm only.

Comment: I will check out whether I have properly downloaded pbf plugin

Comment: Hi @Xaviermoros. Glad I could help you and thanks for accepting my answer. So I guess you finally managed to save the file in `.pbf.osm` format? If not, I think you should just go back in the `Plugins Tab` of the `Preferences Menu` to check the `pbf` plugin. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, I don't know of a method/package to convert a `.shp` file to a `.pbf.osm` file from R. The `sf` library can only read it but not write it.

However, there is a solution using the **opensource software `JOSM`**

### Installing JOSM

To install the software, you can download it from this link https://josm.openstreetmap.de/

### Installing and activating JOSM Plugins

After installing the software, you need to install and activate two plugins. To do this, go to the following menus: `Edit Menu -> Preferences Menu -> Plugins Tab` In the search bar, type :

- `opendata` (this is the plugin to allow `JOSM` software to read `.shp` files)
- `pbf` (this is the plugin to read and save `.pbf.osm` files)

You have to restart the software to make the `opendata` plugin work

**Edit Feb.21, 2023**: You can install plugins at `JOSM` -> `Settings...` (or `Command + ,`) in macOS

### Using JOSM

To use it, this is very simple:

- to open your `.shp` file, go to the `File menu -> Open menu`. In the popup menu of the dialog box you should see the `Shape Files` extension
- to save in `.pbf.osm` format, go to the `File menu -> Save As menu`. In the drop-down menu of the dialog box you should see the extension `pbf compressed files from OSM server (.osm.pbf)`.

And everything should work :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont think JOSM is a good solution. It is extremely sluggish, slow and cant handle datasets that are maybe a bit larger than average.