# R: Calculating the Distance Between Two Geographical Points

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile

I am interested in learning how to work with Road Network Files in R.

For example, I would be interested in finding out the driving distance between the following two (Canadian) addresses:

- CN Tower: 290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9
- Toronto Airport: 6301 Silver Dart Dr, Mississauga, ON L5P 1B2

In the past, I would have used an API such as the OpenStreetMap (OSM):

```
library(tmap)


library(tmaptools)
remotes::install_github("riatelab/osrm")

q1 = geocode_OSM("6301 Silver Dart Dr, Mississauga, ON L5P 1B2")
q2 = geocode_OSM("290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9")

q1 = as.numeric(q1$coords)
q2 = as.numeric(q2$coords)

q1_lat = q1[1]
q1_long = q1[2]
q2_lat = q2[1]
q2_long = q2[2]

route = osrmRoute(src = c(q1[1], q1[2]) ,  dst = c(q2[1], q2[2]), osrm.profile = "car")

> route$distance
[1] 26.2836
```

As we can see here, the driving distance between these two points is 26.2 KM (which is quite close to distance obtained from Google Maps)

**My Question:** I would now like to try and do something similar using a Road Network File.

For example, I found the following file which contains information about the Road Networks (https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/rnf-frr/index2021-eng.cfm?Year=21). I then downloaded this to my computer in .shp format (i.e. shapefile).

**Based on such a file of Road Networks, is it possible to find out the "driving distance" between any two addresses (whether in "language address" or geographical coordinates)?**

Thanks!

**Note:** This file appears to be quite large and I am not sure if my computer can fully load it - is it possible to command the computer to only import a smaller portion of this file? (e.g. import where province = ontario , import where city = toronto)

Comment: Do you need to use that Statcan source? Or would an answer based on another source, limited to the Toronto Metropolitan ground transport network work too?

Comment: @  Nicolás Velásquez : Thank you so much for your reply! I am interested in learning more about this subject and different ways to solve this problem. I was thinking that maybe the Statcan source might be better as (in theory) it should be applicable to anywhere in Canada ... but I am open to learning about different methods. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can download maps and calculate distances based on the information about road networks in these files. You are already using the `osrm` R package. This sends requests to a remote, demo server, which does exactly that. However, the package [docs](https://rdrr.io/cran/osrm/man/osrmTable.html) state,

> The OSRM demo server does not allow large queries (more than 10000 distances or durations).

Instead, you can install [`osrm-backend`](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend), a high performance routing engine written in C++. This will allow you to set up your own routing server, based on maps you provide. You can then make the same requests as above from within R to your local server, with no rate limits.

### Installing osrm-backend and building the map

You are probably correct that you will not be able to easily build the entire Canada map on a standard PC. If you set up your swap file you may be able to but it could take a long time (hours to days). I have used a smaller map, the [Ontario Open Street Map](https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada/ontario.html) data hosted by geofabrik. You can download other regions [here](https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada.html).

The easiest way is to use the OSRM [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend/). Once [docker](https://www.docker.com/) is installed, the following will download the Ontario data and docker image, and start the server. The following is to be entered in a terminal, rather than R. This should work on Windows (in PowerShell), Mac or Linux.

```bash
# Download the map - may take about 15 mins - from https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada/ontario.html
wget -O ontario-latest.osm.pbf https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada/ontario-latest.osm.pbf

# May take 5-10 mins to download the Docker image the first time
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/ontario-latest.osm.pbf || "osrm-extract failed"
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend osrm-partition /data/ontario-latest.osm.pbf || "osrm-partition failed"
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend osrm-customize /data/ontario-latest.osm.pbf || "osrm-customize failed"

# Run the image
docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/ontario-latest.osrm
```

This start a routing engine HTTP server on port 5000. You should see output similar to:

```
[2023-03-27T18:04:02.703986704] [info] starting up engines, v5.27.1
[2023-03-27T18:04:02.704179704] [info] Threads: 8
[2023-03-27T18:04:02.704216504] [info] IP address: 0.0.0.0
[2023-03-27T18:04:02.704250504] [info] IP port: 5000
[2023-03-27T18:04:07.973464309] [info] http 1.1 compression handled by zlib version 1.2.11
[2023-03-27T18:04:07.973828509] [info] Listening on: 0.0.0.0:5000
[2023-03-27T18:04:07.973957909] [info] running and waiting for requests
```

You can then query this from R.

#### Querying the server from R

The important thing is to set your `osrm.server` to the local host:

```
library(osrm)
options("osrm.server" = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
options("osrm.profile" = "car") # Easiest to set this here as well
```

Using the example coordinates from your question, we can do:

```
osrmRoute(src = src, dst = dst)
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 4 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.6122 ymin: 43.61352 xmax: -79.38643 ymax: 43.68883
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#     src dst duration distance                       geometry
# 1_1   1   1 23.25667  26.2836 LINESTRING (-79.61214 43.68...
```

For multiple coordinates, you can also use `osrmTable()`:

```r
osrmTable(src = src, dst = dst)
# $durations
#      1
# 1 23.3

# $sources
#         lon      lat
# 1 -79.61214 43.68332

# $destinations
#         lon      lat
# 1 -79.38643 43.64182
```

Once you've stopped the osrm server Docker container, you only need the last line to run it again, i.e.

```
docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/ontario-latest.osrm
```

If you have a large number of coordinate pairs, you may hit the `max-table-size` parameter. You can increase this by passing it as an argument to `docker run`, e.g.:

```
docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" ghcr.io/project-osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld --max-table-size 100000 /data/ontario-latest.osrm
```

There was a second part of your question about reverse geocoding addresses to lat/lon. It is a sufficiently different question that I'm not going to try to answer it here. However, the good news is there is a [docker image](https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker) for [Nominatim](https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim), which is what `tmaptools::geocode_OSM()` is querying under the hood (again with rate limits). You can install that in a similar way - ask another question if you have trouble.

Comment: @ SamR: thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to do this with using the Road Network file I linked ?

Comment: @stats_noob yes - you just need to convert the shapefile to `.pbf`. I don't know a way to do that in R but there it [seems straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69923744/converting-shp-file-sf-object-to-osm-pbf) using JOSM. I've never done it because I find the geofabrik OSM files are excellent.

Comment: @ SamR: thank you so much for your answer! I will look into how to make this conversion. I have been learning about and trying to teach myself about geospatial analysis (e.g. working with shapefiles) - I have spent some time trying to work with this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851789/r-creating-a-matrix-to-store-join-results ....could you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much!